# How can I add a logo to VLC using command line?

Tags: vlc

I know there is the command line:

`vlc.exe --logo-file="icon.png"`

This only sets the path to the logo but doesn't activate it. So I'm looking for the command line that shows that logo, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. But you also have to tell VLC that you want to display the logo.

For local playback you can do this:

```
vlc --sub-filter logo --logo-file icon.png video.avi
```

If you want to stream the video you have to use the [`transcode`](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html) directive:

```
vlc --logo-file icon.png video.avi --sout "#transcode{vcodec=...,vb=...,sfilter=logo}:std{...}"
```

Check out the VLC wiki page on [how to add logo?](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_add_a_logo/) for more examples.

Comment: hehe seems that this wiki article was published some days after my question here xD

Comment: link is broken [new link](https://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_add_a_logo/)